# Save a tree of all drive in cmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a .bat script, called info.bat

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') DO set datetime=%%I
set datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%


FOR /F "skip=1" %x IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') DO (
tree %x /A /F > info\info-drive-%%x-%datetime%.txt
)
```

But `%x` is `C:` and a filename can't contain ":" and then i tried

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %x IN ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') DO (
set drive=%%x:~0,-1
tree %x\ /A /F > info\info-drive-%drive%-%datetime%.txt
)
```

I was thinking that drive will be `C` but it remain `C:`

I want to create a file for every drive that contain the tree of the disk in the filename.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code did not work because the `for` replaceable parameters do not allow the usage of substring operations. It is necessary to first assign the value to a normal string and then execute the substring operation in this variable.

But, as your code is placed inside a block of code (the `do` clause in the `for` command), you will also need delayed expansion to be able to retrieve the value of the variable changed inside the block.

And, as the output of the `wmic` command includes additional lines (the header you were skipping and ending "blank" lines), you need to filter its output to only retrieve the correct lines (in this sample, the lines that include a colon)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic os get localdatetime /format:list
    ') do set "dateTime=%%a"
    set "datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%"

    for /f %%a in ('
        wmic logicaldisk get caption
        ^| find ":"
    ') do (
        set "drive=%%a"
        set "drive=!drive:~0,1!"
        >"info\info-drive-!drive!-%dateTime%.txt" tree %%a\ /a /f
    )
```

An easier alternative is to directly remove the colon including it as a delimiter in the `for /f` options, and then include the colon in the command where needed.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
        wmic os get localdatetime /format:list
    ') do set "dateTime=%%a"
    set "datetime=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,6%"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%a in ('
        wmic logicaldisk get caption /format:list
    ') do >"info\info-drive-%%a-%dateTime%.txt" tree %%a:\ /a /f
```

By requesting the logicaldisk caption in list format, `wmic` returns lines in the format

```
Caption=C:
```

The `tokens=2 delims==:` makes the `for /f` process the lines as

```
1       2 
v       v .......... Tokens
Caption=C:
       ^ ^ ......... Delimiters
```

As we only request the second token, lines without at least two tokens are discarded (that means the `skip` is now not needed). The second token, the drive letter without the colon, is stored in `%%a` and in the `tree` command we need to include the removed colon.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the very fast reply.